# How to use the unstable branch of cytoscape.js

Tags: cytoscape.js

I'd like to use 'line-gradient-stop-colors' and ''line-gradient-stop-positions' to be able to add some color gradient to my graph edges based on some data. I saw these styles are not included yet in the main cytoscape release so I'd need to use the 'unstable' branch on github. According to the comments [here](https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js/pull/2058)
I should be able to get the branch and do the build. I was able to get the branch doing (then, I can see on node_modules)

```
npm install git://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js.git#unstable --save
```

but how do I do the build so I can use this version on my vue application? And how do I import it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see the [readme file](https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js#build-dependencies) in Cytoscape.js repository. After changing directory to `node_modules/cytoscape/`, you first need to do `npm install` and then build by using `npm  run dist`.

```
cd node_modules/cytoscape/
npm install
npm run dist
```

After building, you should be able to import it as regular.

Comment: Thanks user3140972, that worked out :). I actually read it before but it was still unclear to me.